# Why do floating parent with floating children does not collapse?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why if a `div` element is floating, and has all its children floating, it does not collapse (as a "normal" `div` would do)?

Here there is an example 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOPMPz

#### HTML

```
<div class="float">
  <div class="elem">Elem 1</div>
  <div class="elem">Elem 2</div>
  <div class="elem">Elem 3</div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<br>

<div class="no-float">
  <div class="elem">Elem 1</div>
  <div class="elem">Elem 2</div>
  <div class="elem">Elem 3</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.float {
  background-color: salmon;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  float: left;
}

.no-float {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.elem {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  float: left;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

My expected result was to see both `div`s (`.float` and `.no-float`) collapsing.

Where can I find some resource explaining this?

Comment: this IS the expected result. You should read more about what `float` style does to elements. There is a lot of documentation on the web about this. I suggest MDN ( Mozilla developers docs ) . Also, you have an answer below. That is the correct one

Answer (score 2):

According to Mozilla docs:

> ...when an element is floated, **it is taken out of the normal flow** of the document (though still remaining part of it). It is shifted to the left, or right, until it **touches the edge** of its containing box, or another floated element.

Because it is taken out of the normal flow then the "no-float" div doesn't have any content, so it's height is 0 pixels. When you make the wrapping div float, it is then in this "sub-flow" of the document and actually contains the three floating elements nested inside of it. 
If your layout requires you wrapping div won't be floating you can add `overflow: auto;` to the style of `.no-float` and it will "re-gain" it's height and won't behave as a float element it self.